# Javascript - Array of objects, objects contain another array and an int

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have no idea how to approach this, and I was hoping someone had a little input.  I can't find any information on how to load an array that is inside an Object.  Below is the function I'm concerned with.

```
function Frame(time){
    this.minutes = new Array();
    this.time = time;
}
```

Now if I make an array of Frames, how would I access the minutes array in each Frame?

Comment: You can't access `minutes` as currently written because it is a private variable. See @BrianMains' response in which he uses `this.minutes` to expose it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can also create an array as:

```
function Frame(time){ 
    this.minutes = []; 
    this.time = time; 
}
```

And if you had an array of frames, you would have to loop through and access each frame, grabbing the minutes.

```
for (int i = 0, len = frames.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var min = frames[i].minutes;
    var first = min[0]; // or whatever else is needed
}
```

Comment: It might be worth adding to your answer why `minutes` is inaccessible as written in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  I have one further question.  To access an individual minutes[], could I do something like this?

frames[i].minutes[0]

Comment: @ti30xa Yes, but always do array length checking so that you don't get an exception, but yes.  That's essentially what my sample is doing.